# Help me improve this question

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions

I have been here for a while now, but I have mostly been answering, not asking. My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560643/filesystemobject-get-a-single-file-from-a-folder-using-its-index/) obviously has something wrong with it - indicated by downvotes.

*I'm honestly not here to ask for upvotes or to complain - I myself have downvoted many questions, I know the drill.*

I understand that my question is somehow flawed, I just don't know how to improve it.

**What is wrong with the question?**

- should I remove the variable declarations from the code to make it more to the point?
- is it too theory-inspired? There is no actual programming project behind it, just something that got me wondering.
- is it too stupid/obvious/useless for others?
- I know the MSDN documentation says what I'm looking for is impossible, but we all know that doesn't really mean it is really impossible. Still, maybe I shouldn't ask something like this?
- Should I have referenced the other question I mentioned? It feels irrelevant. Then maybe I shouldn't have mentioned it, as it has nothing to do with my question...

Please point me in the right direction! Thank you!

Comment: It only has a downvote... I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Well, true, but in this topic, I can't really expect more than 10-15 people to read it. I usually write in VBA topics, where we rarely exceed 20-30 views, and voting seldom goes beyond +1 or -1. So in my experience, -1 does mean something. Anyway, thanks, maybe you are right, and it is just one opinion that I can ignore.

Comment: The downvote was reversed.

Comment: Sometimes I downvote just because a question is hot but I think it shouldn't be. But I guess that's not the case here...